# Unable to send the parameter to a Web Service in objective C

Tags: objective-c, web-services

```
NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"abcd",@"UID", nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xyz:8080/cde"] ];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:dict forHTTPHeaderField:@"parameter"];
[request setValue:@"get-employee-details" forHTTPHeaderField:@"serviceName"];
//[request setValue:@"pk703s" forHTTPHeaderField:@"ATTUID"];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *oper = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest: request] ;

[oper setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Success");
    NSLog(@"operation hasAcceptableStatusCode: %d", [operation.response statusCode]);
    NSLog(@"response STring: %@ ", operation.responseString);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure");
    NSLog(@"response: %@", operation.responseString);
    NSLog(@"erro: %@", error.description);
}];
[oper start];
```

Unable to send the parameter throught the request object.
If i dont send the parameter then i am unable to call the service

Answer (score 0):

you're adding post value in your header.

```
NSMutableString *postString = @"myPostValue=value";

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

If you still have problem, check from server side what you get

Comment: I am getting following error:

LoginPage[19044:f803] -[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d65600
2012-10-10 14:05:17.167 LoginPage[19044:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d65600'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14f2022 0xef2cd6 0x14f3cbd

Comment: it means somewhere on you're code, u're passing a [length] message to an object who can't respond to it. Try debugin it and print what class is  0x6d65600 (that will be another pointer adress), or put a breakpoint on throw exception to see where exactly on ur code u get this error

Comment: I am getting above exception at line
[request setValue:dict forHTTPHeaderField:@"parameter"];
0x6d65600 is dict class.
i have a question here, can we set NSDictionary as a value forHTTPHeaderField in request

Comment: No, you need to insert NSString. Like said into the method signature: - (void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field